# Error When Porting Debian to RISC-V: vim-tiny : Depends: vim-common (= 2:8.1.2269-1) but 2:8.2.0378-1 is to be installed

Tags: debian, chroot

Recently I've tried to port Debian on RISC-V and I followed documentation in https://wiki.debian.org/RISC-V. But some error occurs when creating a riscv64 chroot:

[image]

I checked the source in Debian website and found the latest `vim-common` version is 2:8.2, which will be downloaded by default. I'm wondering how to set `mmdebstrap` to download a lower version matching other vim components.

Comment: Are you porting it, or installing it? I think Debian created the port.

Comment: have you tried `apt update`?

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the latest upload of `vim` [fails to build on a number of architectures](https://buildd.debian.org/status/package.php?p=vim) including `riscv64`; because it relies on a shared package, with a strict dependency on the same version, it can’t be installed from unstable on any of those architectures.

The simplest workaround is to install the `minbase` variant using either `debootstrap` or `mmdebstrap`, and complete the chroot with any desired packages afterwards. If necessary, `vim` can then be installed from the last successful build, archived on [snapshot.debian.org](https://snapshot.debian.org/). The following bootstrap command should work:

```
sudo mmdebstrap --architectures=riscv64 --variant=minbase --include="debian-ports-archive-keyring" sid /tmp/riscv64-chroot "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-ports/ sid main" "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-ports/ unreleased main"
```

Comment: Thaks a lot!! I can successfully finish creating chroot now!